# Include PHP command in bash script execute it and exit

Tags: php, bash

I have the folowing script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

target="anotherfolder";
dest="somefolder";

find $dest -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort -r | while IFS= read -r file; do

    while /bin/true; do
        files=$(ls -a "$dest" | grep -Fxv "$ignore")
        if [ "$files" ];
        then
            php "$files" | nc 10.x.x.x 9100
            mv "$files" "$dest"
            break
        fi
    done
done
```

When i run the script is working only with the first file, after that is stop. 
I assume i have to add an exit code after

```
  php "$files" | nc 10.x.x.x 9100
```

Can you help ?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You can't give multiple files as a single argument to `php` or `mv`.

Comment: You never use `$file` in the loop.

Comment: the script is searching for new files, take the file, try to print it via php command via nc on a network printer and after that is moving the file in a folder.

Comment: It's not taking the file. `files=$(ls -a "$dest" | grep -Fxv "$ignore")` is setting `$files` to everything in the `$dest` directory except for `$ignore` (which you never assign).

Comment: `php "$files"` tries to execute the PHP script in `$files`, it doesn't print anything.

Comment: ideea is script without php command is working, if i replace it with lpr for example is printing but i need this php

Comment: Is `$files` a PHP script? You're running the script and piping its output to `nc`.

Comment: Do you want to run `$file` or `$files`? Why do you have `read -r file` if you never use `$file`?

Comment: Files and yes i need all the files in that directory to be printed. Script is working but is not exiting the php command after execution so i need an exit after it. That was the problem not the scipt itself.

Comment: Maybe the PHP script has an infinite loop in it. Or maybe it's waiting for input. What happens if you just run the script by hand?

Answer (score 0):

Barmar is correct. It is also not so clear why you are using `find` command here. You just need only one loop, use below script it might fix your problem. Also always provide the details, exactly what you are trying to do with your script i.e. your requirement that help us to provide a correct answer.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env bash

target="anotherfolder";
dest="somefolder";

#find $dest -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort -r | while IFS= read -r file; do

#while /bin/true; do
 files=$(ls -a "$dest" | grep -Fxv "$ignore")
 for file in files
 do 
    if [ "$file" ];
    then
        php "$file" | nc 10.x.x.x 9100
        mv "$file" "$target"
        #in above you need to move it to another directory
        break
    fi
  done
#done
```

Comment: @Barmar, sorry I did not consider that line. I think he don't need that line at all.

Comment: @Devon, Thanks for your comment I have modified my answer.

Comment: I have two folder. In one of them a php aplication generate a file; a .txt file and i wanna print that file on a thermal printer after that move it to a ,, done " folder.